# Magento 2 and MCOM : syncronize return

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order

My Magento 2 is link to the MCOM (Magento Commerce Order Management).
Currently, I can syncronize orders status between both.

Now, I would like to syncronize return :

If a user want to make a return, he'll call the customer service which will create the return in the MCOM. Then, the MCOM send the return to Magento 2 to create it when I syncronize both.

Presently, I can create RMA in MCOM, but I didn't succeed to syncronize MCOM with Magento to create return in Magento 2. I try to use the same command I used for syncronize orders : `php bin/magento oms:orders:sync`, without success.

Did you have any idea about how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If that can help someone, here some resolution tips :

- Run cron (`bin/magento cron:run`)
- Correctly configure RabbitMQ
- Manually retry failed topic in MCOM > Message Log
- See logs (connector.log, mcom-connector.log, exception.log)